# serial comms with arduino

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port, arduino

I have delete the previous question for simplicity and clarity...

I have written some C# code to send a Byte Array over Serial to an Arduino Nano board (Through a USB to Serial Converter)

Why would I not receive the same HEX Values (in the Arduino serial monitor) as the Values I sent?

(The Values should be the HEX for numbers 0 - 9)

C# Code:

```
if(!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM" + cbCOMPort.Text;

            serialPort1.Open();
        }

        byte[] ByteArr = new byte[10];
        ByteArr[0] = 0x30; 
        ByteArr[1] = 0x31;
        ByteArr[2] = 0x32;  
        ByteArr[3] = 0x33;
        ByteArr[4] = 0x34;
        ByteArr[5] = 0x35;
        ByteArr[6] = 0x36;
        ByteArr[7] = 0x37;
        ByteArr[8] = 0x38;
        ByteArr[9] = 0x39;


        serialPort1.Write(ByteArr, 0, ByteArr.Length);
        serialPort1.Close();
```

Arduino Code:

```
void loop()
{
while (Serial.available()) {
delay(250);
// get the new byte:
byte thisByte = Serial.read(); 
// add it to the inputString:
//inputString += char(intChar);

Serial.print(thisByte,HEX); 
Serial.print(" | ");
}
}
```

Values received in Arduino Serial Monitor:

D6 | B6 | 96 | 76 | 56 | 36 | 16 | F6 | 8D | 0 |

Comment: Hard to see a signal in that noise.  RS-422 uses differential signals, very incompatible with Arduino.  There's at least a hint that the bits are reversed, like 0 turning into 255, suggesting you've got the wires reversed.  Baudrate looks off by a factor of 2.  Just hints, not enough to explain all the values.  Focus on getting the electrical connection right first, ask at electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you @HansPassant, I can understand that RS-422 may pose issues, but I have also found that sending something from my PC to the Arduino over USB to Serial converter, I do not receive the same data at the Arduino that I sent - This leads me to believe that I am missing something fundamental.
I also dont understand what you mean by: "Baudrate looks off by a factor of 2", I will do something far more basic, comunicating from PC to Arduino, and post the results here and on electronics.stackexchange.com as you suggested - Thank You.

Comment: @HansPassant
Changed question to very basic example from PC to Arduino...

Comment: Okay, I see it now, it is just the polarity that is reversed.  That in turn causes it to mis-identify the start bit so you get part of one byte and part of the next one.  Swap the wires.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks Again for the reply.
If I swap TX and RX, I get no Comms?
It is currently wired as follows:
PC's TX goes to Arduino TX
PC's RX goes to Arduino RX
PC GND goes to Arduino GND
I have also understood that TX shold go to RX and RX to TX, but I can't get any comms that way...